# How to report individual jobs of pipeline as GitHub checks for Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

On CI tools like Circle CI, it is possible for your individual jobs of one test run to report as separate checks to Github. The following is the result of one test run, that runs different jobs on Ubuntu and macOS images:

[image]

I can also create a pipeline on Azure Pipelines that achieves a similar result, running on multiple `vmImage`s and different configurations via `matrix`. But this results in only one "check" on Github:

[image]

Although Azure Pipelines itself runs 6 different jobs in this case:

[image]

Is there a way to configure Azure Pipelines to report individual jobs of the pipeline as individual GitHub checks, similar to Circle CI?

Answer (score 5):

I work on Azure Pipelines. We're adding support for showing individual jobs in GitHub Checks right now (our current 3-week sprint). It should be in production in October 2018.

Comment: Awesome David. Keep us updated by updating this answer and replying to my comment here when you did so. Great that you are listening.

Comment: Hi @janpio.  I'm sorry that this feature is later than I anticipated.  The work is complete, but because of holiday deployment schedules, won't make it to production until January.  If you could please send me the name of your repo(s) and your Azure DevOps org (dastahel at microsoft.com), I'll do whatever I can to get it enabled for you early if possible.  Apologies for such a long delay.

Comment: Oh don't worry, I am not in a hurry - just saw this reply again and wondered if you forgot or if reality happened and it comes a bit later ;) Just keep us updated when it is out.

Comment: Just wanted to ask if this made it in for January :)

Comment: Here we are far later than expected (!), but this feature is finally in production and is being enabled in each "ring" of deployment this week.  Everyone should see it by Wednesday, February 13.

Comment: Confirming this is available in production (example: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8859/checks).  Some people have requested the ability to turn _off_ per-job checks to revert back to the old behavior of showing one check per build (no matter how many jobs it contains).  We'll likely add a setting for that.

Comment: @DavidStaheli: Also I see that it apparently works fine on the webpack/webpack repository, I cannot find any options to activate this? I am using a pipeline with a single job which is copied into three using a matrix strategy, but only see a single check on GitHub.

Comment: @ahoereth, we can help diagnose this. Would you mind emailing me the name of your Azure DevOps org, and your GitHub repo (if public) at dastahel at microsoft dot com?

Comment: @DavidStaheli I'm interested in the setting for one check per build (no matter how many jobs). Is this available?

Comment: @DavidStaheli I would also like to see an option (GUI and/or YAML) to bring back the old behavior of just one summary check/status. Having 20 individual jobs show up is a little spammy if there are also other checks of interest.

Comment: @DavidStaheli I used to have one check per job, but since 10 days or so GH suddenly show a check for each image defined in the matrix. Would be easy to turn off this behaviour.

Comment: @DavidStaheli How to show just a single check per build?